# How to make UITableView ignore UINavigationController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

So I have this screen:

[Current TableViewController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9w34J.png)

This image is a subview of a UIView, which I use as a header for a table:

```
class CoursesDetailPageHeader: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
    }

    func setDefaultImage() {
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "header")
    }
}
```

And my tableView:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let headerNib = UINib(nibName: "CoursesDetailPageHeader", bundle: nil)
    tableView.register(headerNib, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "pageHeader")
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 220
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let pageHeader = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "pageHeader") as! CoursesDetailPageHeader
    pageHeader.setDefaultImage()

    return pageHeader
}
```

What should I do, to bring the tableView to the top, so that there is no empty space (where the transparent navController)?

UPD:
To show what I want to have:
[Desired TableViewController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8Y4H.png)

SOLVED:
Thank to @kathayatnk issue was solved with the following code:

```
let statusBarHeight = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height
let navigationBarHeight = navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.size.height
let insets = UIEdgeInsets(top: -(statusBarHeight + navigationBarHeight), left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
self.tableView.contentInset = insets
```

Comment: If you are using auto-layout. try constraining tableView top to margin instead of topLayout guid with 0 value. This should display the  table view all the way from top of your screen and behind the transparent navigation bar

Comment: I want navigationBar to be as it is, but make tableView ignore it, so the header appears behind the navBar, not under it

Comment: @RomanM.what do you mean by header behind your nav bar? Header is part of the table view and it scrolls together with it

Comment: @RomanM. If I understood correctly, you want [this](https://ibb.co/kyiTFF)  effect right?

Comment: @FangmingNing I updated the question

Comment: @kathayatnk exactly

Comment: so all you have to do is, constraint the top of tableView to top margins, that will put the table view behind the navBar

Comment: @RomanM. Like [This](https://ibb.co/mpkVUa)

Comment: @kathayatnk but I have tableviewcontroller, not tableview inside viewcontroller. it's already linked to all sides of the controller

Comment: @ramzesenok I've added some code snippet, put that in viewDidLoad method. It should do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably set the insets of the embedded tableView

```
let insets = UIEdgeInsets(top: -64.0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
self.tableView.contentInset = insets;
```

Comment: great, my pleasure

Answer (score 1):

For this you have to do `UINavigationBar` `Translucent`

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = true
    UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
    UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)

    return true
}
```

Comment: You're welcome..... :) you should accept correct answer as per stackoverflow guideline so that other people can get help having same issue!

Comment: unfortunately nothing happens

Comment: what issue you have face ?

Comment: no new issue. just nothing happened. all stays as it was

Comment: @PiyushPatel tried to put it in TableViewController as well as in AppDelegate. result is the same

Comment: @ramzesenok i have posted my answer